# Migrated master repo from Bitbucket to Github. How to reconnect cloned repo to new Github repo?

Tags: git, github

Pretty straight forward.  I have an app running on a local server that was cloned from a Bitbucket repo.  I moved that repo over to Github and was wondering if there was a way to connect my cloned repo to the new Github repo?  Or do I have to delete the cloned repo and make a clone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new remote that points to the new repo or change the url for the remote that you have already set to have the new repo url.

```
git help remote
```

Then, add a new remote (yes, you can have more than one remote set up on a repo):

```
git remote add new-repo the-url
git fetch new-repo
```

or (assuming the old remote is called origin):

```
git remote set-url origin the-new-url
git fetch origin
```